# RxJS Pluck Undefined for property

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm unable to get the right value from `pluck` when used with `Rx.DOM.getJSON`. I have a JSON endpoint set up at `/resource1` serving a static array of objects:

```
[{ name: "Alpha" }, { name: "Beta" }]
```

I then put this in an observable:

```
let source1 = Rx.DOM.getJSON("/resource1");
```

Then I subscribe to that observable:

```
source1.subscribe(
    (value) => { console.log("Received value: ", value); }
);
```

As expected, it logs out the string "Received value: " and two objects, each with a `name` property. However, when I add `pluck` to the end of the observable:

```
let source1 = Rx.DOM.getJSON("/resource1").pluck("name");
```

It logs out "Received value: undefined". If I instead do this in the subscribe function:

```
source1.subscribe(
    (value) => { console.log("Received value", value.map((i) => { return i.name; })); }
)
```

I get the two name values, as expected. If I try a modified version of the example from [the RxJS documentation on pluck](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pluck.md), it returns the name values as expected:

```
let source3 = Rx.Observable.from([{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]).pluck("name");

source3.subscribe(
    (value) => { console.log("Received value: ", value); }
);
```

Why does `Rx.DOM.getJSON("/resource1").pluck("name");` return undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on the [forums for the book I was referencing](https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/364/topics/13945). The problem is that `getJSON` returns a single event rather than an stream of events, so `pluck` will not work in it directly. To use `pluck` you first have to convert it to a stream of events using `flatMap` with `fromArray`.

```
Rx.DOM.getJSON("/resource1").flatMap(Rx.Observable.fromArray).pluck("name");
```